# How to create a gem that serves static assets to Rails 3 & Rails 4 projects

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

We've been trying to make a gem that servers our CSS files to our Rails 3 and Rails 4 projects. With a gem we should be able to make a change in only one spot, the gem, to make a visual change for ALL our projects.

Except, all tutorials we've found are no longer up to date or don't work. Using the tutorial from [Rake Routes](http://rakeroutes.com/blog/write-a-gem-for-the-rails-asset-pipeline/) we've come to the following situation to create a *minimal* gem that adds a CSS file to Rails 3 and Rails 4 projects

**Gemspec**

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "static_assets/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "static_assets"
  s.version     = StaticAssets::VERSION
  s.authors     = ["Etienne van Delden"]
  s.email       = ["evdelden@i-level.nl"]
  s.homepage    = "http://www.i-level.nl"
  s.summary     = "Summary of StaticAssets."
  s.description = "Description of StaticAssets."

  s.files       = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.test_files  = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")

  s.add_dependency "rails", ">= 3.1"
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]

  s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
end
```

**lib/static_assets.rb**

```
require "static_assets/engine"

module StaticAssets
end
```

**lib/static_assets/engine.rb**

```
module StaticAssets
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    initializer 'static_assets.load_static_assets' do |app|
      app.middleware.use ::ActionDispatch::Static, "#{root}/vendor"
    end
  end
end
```

**vendor/assets/stylesheets/our_awesome_static_assets.css**

```
body{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

This appears to be the minimal code to create a gem. It `rake builds` successfully, so does `rake release`

But when adding the gem to our Rails 3 project, it cannot find the CSS file:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'static_assets'
```

**application.css**

```
*= require static_assets
```

When start the project and go to the index page, we get the following error:

```
 Sprockets::FileNotFound in Sessions#new

Showing *snipped*/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #14 raised:

couldn't find file 'static_assets'
  (in *snipped*/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:4)
```

What do we need to change to get a minimal code example for adding stylesheets to a Rails project that supports Rails 3 AND Rails 4?

*Code can be found on [Github](http://github.com/evdelden/static_assets)*

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem a few months ago - [exception_handler](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler)

[Our gem uses custom assets](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/tree/master/app/assets) (not CSS, only images) which I'll be able to detail here:

--

**Engine**

When you write a gem for Rails, [you're *really* writing an engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#generating-an-engine) which can be included in your Rails app.

The most basic explanation for this is that when you load a gem, it will actually append "hidden" files & functionality to your app. Not magic or wizardry - literally just adds new file to your app's runtime environment, allowing you to call that functionality as if you'd written it yourself.

When I understood this, the gem creation process became much simpler...

--

**Assets**

I think you'll be best putting your assets into the following file structure:

```
app
|-- assets
|    |-- stylesheets
|    |   |-- static_assets
|    |   |   |-- static_assets.css
```

This will give your *engine* the ability to use / create the files you need, allowing you to get them to work on your behalf. As with a lot of other Rails-based gems, the Rails environment will load the asset pipeline based on the files it has available.

As I mentioned - an engine is *really* there to "inject" files into your application at run time. This means, as with other gems, such as the [`twitter-bootstrap-rails`](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-stylesheets-with-less) gem, you'll have to call those injected files as below:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/*
  *= require static_assets/static_assets
*/
```

This should work for you - if not, we'll have to investigate in the comments!

Comment: Thanks! With the changes you suggested, the gem is now working in our Rails 4 project! The only problem I have now is that it doesn't work in our Rails 3 project. Is it even possible to make a single gem to support both versions of rails?